# Why to regard, in a natural way, the generic element of $L^p$, i.e. the whole equivalence class, as a function defined almost everywhere?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $(X,\mathcal{A},\mu)$ be a measure space. Let $f, g\colon X \to \overline{\mathbb{R}}$ be a measurable functions. We say that $$f\sim g \iff f=g\quad\text{a.e}$$ This is a equivalence relation on the set of measurable functions.

We define the vector space for $p\in [1,\infty)$

$$\mathcal{L}^p(X,\mathcal{A},\mu):=\left\{f\colon X\to \overline{\mathbb{R}}\; |\; \text{f is measurable and}\quad \rVert f\lVert_p<\infty\right\},$$ where

$$\rVert f\lVert_p:=\left[\int_X |f|^p\; d\mu\right]^{\frac{1}{p}}.$$

Since we want a norm, we define the quotient space $$L^p(X,\mathcal{A},\mu):=\mathcal{L}^p(X,\mathcal{A},\mu)/\sim.$$ An element of $L^p$ is an equivalence class $[f]$, where $$[f]:=\left\{g\in\mathcal{L}^p\;|\; g=f\quad \text{a.e.}\right\}$$

In all the texts the following thing is said: we can identify each equivalence class with its representative without creating problems, or equivalently we can consider the generic element of $L^p$ as a function defined almost everywhere.

**Question.** Why can we consider the generic element of $L_p$, i.e. the equivalence class, as a function defined almost everywhere?

**Reply to peek-a-boo's comment**
I don't understand what you are saying. Now let me explain better.

If $g\in [f]$, then $g=f$ a.e. and therefore the set $N:=\{f\ne g\}$ has zero measure.
Now if we disregard the definition of $g$ over $N$, we obtain a function $g\colon X\setminus N\to \overline{\mathbb{R}}$ defined a.e. Then, eventually redefining the function $g$ on $N$ as zero, we see that $[g]=[f]$. That's why I said that every equivalence class can be represented in infinite ways by a function defined almost everywhere. Conversely, every function defined almost everywhere identifies an equivalence class by means of the projection to the quotient. In this sense it is natural to identify all the elements of the same class, thinking of it as a single function defined almost everywhere.

Is this reasoning formally correct?

**What would I like** I would like to find an explanation for the fact that a generic element of the space $L^p$, ie an equivalence class, can be considered as a function defined almost everywhere.

**Reply to Paul Sinclair's comment**
I understand what you are saying. Now, however, I report exactly what I found written in the text *Measure Theory and Nonlinear evolution equations* written by F. Smarrazzo and A.Tesei.

[image]

With $\mathcal{N}_{\mu}$ is denoted the set of $\mu-$ null set. I don't understand for some reason it is *natural* to make this identification.

Comment: Each representative of the equivalence class is by definition a function. The equivalence relation is by definition “equality a.e”. Putting these two together, you can think of the equivalence class as being ‘any function that is defined a.e’. In other words, when speaking plainly and phrasing many theorems, you use the language of ‘functions’ with the caveat ‘a.e’ inserted appropriately, instead of using the more formal and cumbersome language of equivalence classes.

Comment: @peek-a-booThanks! A last question for you: Is it true or false that every equivalence class can be represented in infinite ways by a function defined almost everywhere? and if so why?

Comment: false. This all depends on the measure at hand. For example think of any set with the counting measure. Then “equality a.e” means the same thing as “equality” (in the usual sense for functions). But usually, when dealing with things like Lebesgue measure on a set of positive measure, then sure because singletons have zero measure (so there are infinitely many measure zero sets).

Comment: @peek-a-booI replied to you by editing the post. Thanks for your interest.

Comment: As I’ve already said, with the counting measure, equality a.e is the same as equality everywhere. In your notation it means the set $N$ is empty. So the equivalence class contains a unique representative.

Comment: @peek-a-booI fail to understand why a function of Lp can be considered a function defined almost everywhere.

Comment: Personally, I would never use this description for the elements of $L^p$. In the case of Lebesgue measure on $\Bbb R^n$, treating them as functions defined almost everywhere misses their actual ambiguity, while giving a false concept about their nature. if $f \in L^p$, there is not even one value of $x$ where we can claim a definitive value of $f(x)$. So in that sense, they are defined *nowhere*.  We can think of them as functions, but for which we choose to ignore any discrepancies that are limited to sets of measure $0$.

Comment: @PaulSinclairThanks for interest. I answered you in the post.

Comment: You can think that you are just choosing one of the class ... but then it is different from the others of the class in a set of measure $0$, so you remember to not take into account these values. All these functions that are equal almost everywhere have then the same properties with respect to integration that the first one you chose.